# Creating buttons/input fields

Tags: buttons

The options/customization as well as the install packages buffers demonstrate that it is possible to have buttons, links and input fields.

Is this something one could fairly easily duplicate to create a form?

Currently I use a mixture of `read-string`, `completing-read` and ORG capture templates to generate a "form" where one can use <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to check off items done.  The problems with this approach are:

- all questions are asked in the message bar, which is easy to miss
- once an option was given, you cannot review and/or return/adjust the information you entered without having to start over
- since I start with the ORG capture template, the time recorded is the time this task started (not so important to me), but not when it was completed (much more important).

My goal is to replace the `read-string` and `completing-read` items with a form where people can more naturally move fore and aft to fill in the information using <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>RET</kbd> or even use the mouse to check off items they completed (like one can click to enable/disable a color theme).

While I am currently using ORG mode, it is not a requirement if buttons would need a different mode to work.

Comment: Why did I get a close vote?  If something is off with this question, it would be helpful to at least get a comment on what can be done to improve it or why it is believed to need closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the widget library (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html). See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html#Programming-Example for an example use that has several features you describe in your question (multiple choice, select multiple, text fields, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  That looks very promising.  I will see about follow up on all links and come back to vote.

Comment: That is really what I was looking for.  Thanks again!