# Widgets: How to notify on exiting "editable-field"

Tags: widget, buttons

This is a follow-up on [Creating buttons/input fields](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/68016/23319).

I learned that forms (or rather its elements) in Emacs are called widgets and I am now experimenting on how I can get the best result for what I like to build.

Since some `editable-field` values shall be used with some (external) commands and evaluated to fill other fields, I wonder if one could limit the `:notify` property (or something similar) to only trigger when exiting the field (e.g. when pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>RET</kbd>) rather than on every single character change.  This is to reduce the amount the attached command is run to once when I am done with the field.

Comment: I don't see a way to hook into notify for this. TAB and RET don't seem to trigger an event for an editable-field that runs the :notify function.

I wonder if the way to do it would be to advise `widget-field-activate`, `widget-forward`, and `widget-backward` so that before they run, they could run an update function (probably not the one for notify though?

Comment: As long as there are alternatives, which can trigger upon exiting a widget, it does not need to specifically run commands through `:notify` inside a specific widget.  Though I think it is dedicated for that pupose.  An example of a command I want to run is to use a name to find the login in an LDAP tree.  For obvious reasons I do not want to spam LDAP with unfinished names to find the login, but have it only search for it once I am done entering the name.  Of course, I can introduce a button to manually search for it, but would prefer an automated solution.